# How to fix NativeScript error: "Main entry is missing. App cannot be started. Verify app bootstrap."

Tags: typescript, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

I am trying to build my NativeScript app on Android. The app compiles without errors, but when I try to build in an emulator, I get the following error:

"Error: Main entry is missing. App cannot be started. Verify app bootstrap."

We have already tried deleting node_modules and package-lock.json and running yarn/npm install but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

This is what my package.json looks like:

```
{
 "description": "NativeScript Application",
 "license": "SEE LICENSE IN <your-license-filename>",
 "readme": "NativeScript Application",
 "repository": "<fill-your-repository-here>",
 "nativescript": {
 "id": "*****",
 "tns-android": {
 "version": "5.4.0"
 }
 },
 "dependencies": {
 "@angular/animations": "^7.2.15",
 "@angular/common": "^7.2.15",
 "@angular/compiler": "^7.2.15",
 "@angular/core": "^7.2.15",
 "@angular/forms": "^7.2.15",
 "@angular/http": "^7.2.15",
 "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.2.15",
 "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.2.15",
 "@angular/router": "^7.2.15",
 "@firebase/app": "^0.1.7",
 "angular": "^1.7.2",
 "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.6",
 "copy-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.3",
 "cross-spawn": "^5.1.0",
 "firebase": "^6.1.0",
 "http-signature": "^1.2.0",
 "moment": "^2.20.1",
 "nativescript-angular": "^7.2.4",
 "nativescript-directions": "^1.1.2",
 "nativescript-email": "^1.5.1",
 "nativescript-material-icons": "^1.0.3",
 "nativescript-ng2-fonticon": "^1.3.4",
 "nativescript-plugin-firebase": "^8.3.2",
 "nativescript-theme-core": "^1.0.4",
 "npmlog": "^4.1.2",
 "reflect-metadata": "~0.1.8",
 "request": "^2.88.0",
 "rxjs": "^6.3.3",
 "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.2",
 "string-similarity": "^1.2.0",
 "tns-core-modules": "^5.4.2",
 "webpack": "^4.33.0",
 "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
 },
 "devDependencies": {
 "@angular/cli": "^7.3.9",
 "@angular/compiler-cli": "8.0.0",
 "@ngtools/webpack": "8.0.0",
 "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
 "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
 "babel-traverse": "^6.26.0",
 "babel-types": "^6.26.0",
 "babylon": "6.4.5",
 "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "~3.0.0",
 "lazy": "1.0.11",
 "nativescript-dev-sass": "^1.2.0",
 "nativescript-dev-typescript": "^0.10.0",
 "nativescript-dev-webpack": "^0.24.1",
 "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
 "typescript": "^3.1.4",
 "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "~1.1.6",
 "webpack-cli": "^3.3.3"
 }
}
```

This is the entire stack trace:

```
An uncaught Exception occurred on "main" thread.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{*****/com.tns.NativeScriptActivity}: com.tns.NativeScriptException: 
Calling js method onCreate failed

Error: Main entry is missing. App cannot be started. Verify app bootstrap.
File: "file:///data/data/*****/files/app/vendor.js, line: 21779, column: 20

StackTrace: 
    Frame: function:'push.../node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/frame.js.ActivityCallbacksImplementation.setActivityContent', file:'file:///data/data/*****/files/app/vendor.js', line: 21779, column: 27
    Frame: function:'push.../node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/frame.js.ActivityCallbacksImplementation.onCreate', file:'file:///data/data/*****/files/app/vendor.js', line: 21624, column: 14
    Frame: function:'push.../node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/activity.js.NativeScriptActivity.onCreate', file:'file:///data/data/*****/files/app/vendor.js', line: 19438, column: 25


    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
Caused by: com.tns.NativeScriptException: 
Calling js method onCreate failed

Error: Main entry is missing. App cannot be started. Verify app bootstrap.
File: "file:///data/data/*****/files/app/vendor.js, line: 21779, column: 20

StackTrace: 
    Frame: function:'push.../node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/frame.js.ActivityCallbacksImplementation.setActivityContent', file:'file:///data/data/*****/files/app/vendor.js', line: 21779, column: 27
    Frame: function:'push.../node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/frame.js.ActivityCallbacksImplementation.onCreate', file:'file:///data/data/*****/files/app/vendor.js', line: 21624, column: 14
    Frame: function:'push.../node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/activity.js.NativeScriptActivity.onCreate', file:'file:///data/data/*****/files/app/vendor.js', line: 19438, column: 25


    at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native Method)
    at com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:1203)
    at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:1083)
    at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1070)
    at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1050)
    at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1042)
    at com.tns.NativeScriptActivity.onCreate(NativeScriptActivity.java:19)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
    ... 9 more
```

Comment: The error says that the `main` entry specified in your `scr/package.json` (e.g. `"main": "main.js",`) cannot be found or does not contain a `bootstrapModule` call. I suppose you are using nativescript@5.4.0 and run `tns run android`. Do you have a sample application somewhere? (you could also try in a new app (`tns create newApp --ng && cd newApp && tns run android`)

Comment: can you share your main.ts ?

Comment: I have this problem too

Answer (score -3):

Add this sample code in `main.ts` file.

```
import { platformNativeScriptDynamic } from "nativescript-angular/platform";
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { AppModule } from "./app/app.module";

enableProdMode();
platformNativeScriptDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```